# Writing regression equation in plot python

Tags: python, plot, equation

I've done a regression so I obtained:

```
slope_b = -0.7583790156301706
intercept_b = 7.22190409922338
r_value_b = -0.887981466827434
```

I want to add the regression equation into the plot like:

```
y = -0.76x + 7.22
r = -0.88
```

As I couldn't find the way to do it I did like a text:

```
axarr[0].text(8,6,'y=-0.76x+7.22')
axarr[0].text(9,5, 'r²=-0.88')
```

However, I add variables all the time to the regression so the slope, intercept and r_value are changing so I have to change the expression every time. I did some research and I found this:

```
axarr[0].text(8,6,'y=', slope_b, '*x+', intercept_b)
```

But I didn't get the wanted result.
Also, is there a way to have these values with just two decimals?
I prefer a shorter number in the equation rather than this: -0.7583790156301706.

Comment: What is `axarr`? Which libraries do you use? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried `axarr[0].text(9,5, 'r²=-0.88')` -> `axarr[0].text(9.5, 'r²=-0.88')` etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it:

```
axarr[0].plot(x,y,'r', label="y={0:.2f}x+{1:.2f}\nr{2:.2f}".format(slope_b,intercept_b,r_value_b), color='black')
axarr[0].legend()
```

where {0:.2f} makes the number with two decimals